# extra y ticks not shown as yticks with scaled y ticks

Tags: pgfplots

How can I show the extra y ticks as the rest of the labels on y axis?
[image]
Here is my MWE, I tried

```
scaled extra y ticks=real:1000
```

commented out in code but without success.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%============================================================
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
area style,
/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,
scaled y ticks=real:1000,
ytick scale label code/.code={kEUR},
%scaled extra y ticks=real:1000,
extra y ticks={3311361},
extra y tick style={grid=major,grid style={color=red},tick label style={color=red}},
extra x ticks={8.77,15},
extra x tick style={grid=major,color=red,grid style={color=red},
},
]
\addplot[color=violet,fill=violet!20] table[x=X,y=Y]
{X  Y
0   -5957500
1   -5191175
2   -4448748
3   -3729541
4   -3032897
5   -2358177
6   -1704762
7   -1072048
8   -459449
9   133602
10  707662
11  1263267
12  1800939
13  2321185
14  2824499
15  3311361
16  3782234
17  4237573
18  4677817
19  5103392
20  5514715
}
\closedcycle ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the extra tick scaling in `extra y tick style={}`. As the multiplicator would get printed as well (`\cdot 1000` in red), I inserted the `ytick scale label code/.code={}` which will print nothing instead.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    area style,
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep=,
    scaled y ticks=real:1000,
    ytick scale label code/.code={kEUR},
    extra y ticks={3311361},
    extra y tick style={scaled y ticks=real:1000,ytick scale label code/.code={},grid=major,grid style={color=red},tick label style={color=red}},
    extra x ticks={8.77,15},
    extra x tick style={grid=major,color=red,grid style={color=red},
    },
    ]
    \addplot[color=violet,fill=violet!20] table[x=X,y=Y]
    {X  Y
        0   -5957500
        1   -5191175
        2   -4448748
        3   -3729541
        4   -3032897
        5   -2358177
        6   -1704762
        7   -1072048
        8   -459449
        9   133602
        10  707662
        11  1263267
        12  1800939
        13  2321185
        14  2824499
        15  3311361
        16  3782234
        17  4237573
        18  4677817
        19  5103392
        20  5514715
    }
    \closedcycle ;
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]